# Why does SOQL-Query to Custom Object fail?

Tags: soql, query, c#, .net

I have created a custom object in our Salesforce, named Event with the API-name Event__c. It has fields Name__c and Description__c. I would like to perform a query on that object by firing the following SOQL-statement via a .NET-Force.com-API-Client-Call, rceiving the following response:

```
SELECT Name__c, Description__c FROM Event__c
                                    ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:37
sObject type 'Event__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a 
    custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please 
    reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

What am I doing wrong? I added the __c, so this can't be the main issue. Is it because the Table is still empty? In that case I would expect an empty result, not an error, right? Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using REST or SOAP?

Comment: Can you confirm that your org doesn't have a namespace set ie. that "Namespace Prefix" on your Event object is blank? If you do have a namespace set, then you will need to prefix the object and field names with `yournsprefix__`.

Comment: Does your API user have access to the Event__c object in his profile/permission sets?

Comment: REST, Dan! / Lieven: Where can I/my SF-admin check that?

Comment: Keith: I am pretty sure that we don't have that. Where would I be able to check that?

Comment: Lieven: Okay, I just checked. It is listed under Profile -> Custom Field-Level Security. When I click view, everything is checked and should be accessible, right?

Comment: Few things you should check: What user do you use in your integration? What is the profile of this user? On the profile do you have a least read permission? To check the read permission go to Setup>Manage users>Profiles> Open the user's profile definition > Under custom object permissions check the event object and validate if at least read is checked

Comment: @Christian Field Level security doesn't mean they have access to the object itself. For instance, if you have an `Employee__c` object, some users may need access to that object to change things like contact details, but field level security ultimately makes sure they couldn't see, for example, banking details.